# Print invoice in Java with different Font Sizes

Tags: java

I am using below code for printing invoice. I format invoice in a string and pass to this code. This is working fine. but i need to add some static text and increase the text size. (Shop Title). Is there any way to do it with this approach or do i need to find a completely different approach.

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobAdapter;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;


public class GenerateInvoice {

    public static void printInvoice(String invoice) throws IOException {
      try {
          PrintService mPrinter = null;
          Boolean bFoundPrinter = false;

          PrintService[] printServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

          for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
              String sPrinterName = printService.getName();
              if (sPrinterName.equals("EPSON LQ-310")) {
                  mPrinter = printService;
                  bFoundPrinter = true;
              }
          }
          String testData = invoice+"\f";
          InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(testData.getBytes());
          DocFlavor flavor =  DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE   ;

          PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
          System.out.println(service);

          DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
          Doc doc= new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);

          PrintJobWatcher pjDone = new PrintJobWatcher(job);

          job.print(doc, null);

          pjDone.waitForDone();

          is.close();
      } catch (PrintException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  static class PrintJobWatcher {
      boolean done = false;

      PrintJobWatcher(DocPrintJob job) {
          // Add a listener to the print job
          job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
              public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                  allDone();
              }
              public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                  allDone();
              }
              public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                  allDone();
              }
              public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                  allDone();
              }
              void allDone() {
                  synchronized (PrintJobWatcher.this) {
                      done = true;
                      PrintJobWatcher.this.notify();
                  }
              }
          });
      }
      public synchronized void waitForDone() {
          try {
              while (!done) {
                  wait();
              }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          }
      }
  }

}
```

Please give me some help to resolve this matter.

```
String head = String.format("%30s\n\n", "   TITLE   ");
String s = String.format("%5s %10s %15s %20s\n", "Description","Unit","Quantity","Net Amount");
String output = head + s;
```

This is how i format the string. but no idea how to increase the text size.

Comment: What does the content of the `invoice` argument look like?  As Steve pointed out, without knowing what it contains, it is not possible to change any fonts, since you are not explicitly rendering any text to begin with.

Comment: I am using only "String.format" to format the text.

Comment: i added string formatting part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing plain text.  By definition, plain text has no font information and appears entirely in the same font.  With most printers, the solution would be to create a simple HTML document and print it as [DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_HTML](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/print/DocFlavor.STRING.html#TEXT_HTML), or to create a rich text component like a [JEditorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) and use its inherited [print method which takes a PrintService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#print%28java.text.MessageFormat,java.text.MessageFormat,boolean,javax.print.PrintService,javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet,boolean%29).

But, your case is a special case.  You are printing to a [dot matrix printer](https://www.epson.com.ph/Dot-Matrix-Printers/Epson-LQ-310-Dot-Matrix-Printer/p/C11CC25301).  I honestly don’t know whether you can print graphics at all;  the printer is capable of monochrome graphics, but the native printer driver may or may not provide that capability in a way that is compatible with a Java [Printable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/print/Printable.html).

However, the printer does appear to support ESC/P2 printer escape codes.  This means you can probably print some text in double-width mode:

```
String title = "TITLE";
String titleIndent = 32 - title.length;
String head = String.format("%" + titleIndent + "s\n\n", "\u000e" + title);
```

The `"\u000e"` is the ESC/P2 character which enables double-width characters for the rest of the line.  See http://lprng.sourceforge.net/DISTRIB/RESOURCES/PPD/epson.htm.

You might also want to underline it:

```
String head = String.format("%" + titleIndent + "s\n\n",
    "\u001b-1\u000e" + title + "\u001b-0");
```

`"\u001b-1"` (ESC hyphen 1) turns underline on, and 
`"\u001b-0"` (ESC hyphen 0) turns underline off.

Answer (score 0):

This code has the contents of the invoice to be printed in a string, and could certainly edit that string prior to printing it.  So it seems on the surface that you could certainly do what you're asking via this code.

I wonder, however, if this is where you should be doing this.  This code seems to be responsible for printing a document without having to know anything about its content, or even the file type.  For this code to make changes to the document, it will have to take on a whole new role and understand the format and contents of the documents it's printing.

There is not enough information here to allow any specific guidance on where this logic that modifies the contents of the document should go.  My gut says it doesn't belong here...that there might be somewhere earlier in the process that already has knowledge of the contents of the document, and that the modifications you are seeking to make should be applied there.  But if this is the only place these changes can be made, there's no reason I can see that this code couldn't modify the string it is given in pretty much any conceivable way before printing it.  It would just need to know enough to do so properly, which again, is a function of specifics not provided here.